# Regular expression class inside another class in Python 3.5

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to find this regular expression `[A-Z0-9]+-` in a string.

The problem is, I don't know how many times it may repeat, so this isn't an option: `[A-Z0-9]+-[A-Z0-9]+-[A-Z0-9]+-`.

I tried to use `[[A-Z0-9]+-]+` but as it turns out the outer brackets will restrict the functionality of the inner brackets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply a `+` (one or more occurrences) to a grouping construct `(?:...)` (a non-capturing group):

```
(?:[A-Z0-9]+-)+
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qD3qT5/1)

Comment: Yes! Just what I needed. Thanks for showing the regex101.com website